# when a bimodule is a right module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, bimodules

This is a claim in Loday's Cyclic Homology as follows:
Let $k$ be a commutative ring, $A$ be a $k$-algebra, and $M$ be a bimodule over $A$. Then, when $A$ is unital (has a unit $1\in A$ s.t. $1m= m1=1$), the bimodule $M$ is equivalent to a right $A\otimes A^{op}$-module via $m(a\otimes a')= ama'$.

There seems to be a simple observation to make this work but I can't see it. Any hints are appreciated.

Edit regarding the comments below: By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimodule), an $A-A-$bimodule has the following action $(am)a'=a(ma')$. I don't see why one would rephrase this action as a right action of $A\otimes A^{op}$ via $m(a\otimes a')= ama'$, and not for example a right $A\otimes A$-module action given by the same formula. That is, why $A^{op}$?

Comment: have you tried to chase through the definition using the identification? this should really be a straight forward identification of left and right actions working out via the identity (that is why you need it). I currently am not sure how I can make the above statement any clearer, so I would need t see precisely where the hiccup is.

Comment: Another to phrase this is that "$(A,A)$-bimodule" and "right $A \otimes A^\text{op}$-module" are two ways to say the same thing, in exactly the same sense that "abelian group" and "$\mathbb{Z}$-module" are two ways to say the same thing.

Comment: However, the formula given here is incorrect! To view $M$ as a right $A \otimes A^\text{op}$-module we need to define $m(a \otimes a') = a'ma$. I think it's more natural to say that $M$ is equivalent to a *left* $A \otimes A^\text{op}$-module via $(a \otimes a')m = ama'$.